# R shinyhelper fails with htmlOutput

Tags: r, shiny

R shinyhelper's `observe_helpers` function does not see helpers passed through an output function like `htmlOutput`, which is unfortunate because it is an otherwise useful little package. The following is a MWE.

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyhelper)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "var",
                  choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D")) %>% 
        helper(icon="question",                                          
               type="markdown",
               content="herp")),        
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("selected"))
))
```

**Server**

```
server = function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$var, {
    if(input$var=="B"){
       output$selected <- renderUI({ 
                            fluidRow(
                              column(4,textInput(inputId="derp",
                                                 label="derp") %>% 
                                         helper(icon="question", 
                                                type="markdown",                                                                 
                                                content="flerp")),
                              column(8))})
}})

  observeEvent(input$derp, {print(input$derp)})

  observe_helpers()  

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I am aware that `helper` works when connected by pipe to `htmlOutput`, but this is not helpful when we want to render a UI in the server that contains multiple widgets with their own helpers.

Any suggestions for how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now update to shinyhelper v0.3.1, which should fix this issue.